# Getting all children of a list as a collection (IList<T> collection passed)

Tags: c#, linq, generics

In short I have a `IList<T>`, I would like to get all the children properties of the list as a collection and be able to query for properties of each children, and the property name of the children is a string hence why i have that extension class to help me get property values.

I may be able to use `list.SelectMany()`, however I a not sure how to use that given the name of my property is a string and casting it as a selector is one part I am not sure about.

I have added my problem questions into the code below

```
public void Process<T>(IList<T> list)
{
    ........

    var childList = (from u in list from e in (u.GetPropertyValue("Images") as IEnumerable<object>) select e).ToList(); 

    //How do i bring back IList<T>, following line returns null

    var childList2 = (from u in list from e in (u.GetPropertyValue("Images") as IEnumerable<T>) select e).ToList(); //or as IList<T> will also return null

    BulkInsert(childList, "Images",  conn, tran);
}

private void BulkInsert<T>(IList<T> list, string tableName, SqlConnection conn, SqlTransaction tran)
{
    var props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T))
                    .Cast<PropertyDescriptor>()
                    .ToArray();
   //(HERE LIES MY REAL ISSUE, as i am not getting list of properties for  each item in the list 
   //props  is BLANK (assuming because the type passed in is object and object has no "properties"), the same code works if I am passing List<Something> and it brings back all properties of Something
}

public static class PropertyExtension
{
    public static void SetPropertyValue(this object obj, string propName, object value)
    {
        obj.GetType().GetProperty(propName).SetValue(obj, value, null);
    }
    public static object GetPropertyValue(this object src, string propName)
    {
        return src.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(src, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are processing runtime types. So forget about generics. Generics are only useful for compile time types.

Fix the BulkInsert:

```
private void BulkInsert(Type type, string tableName, SqlConnection conn, SqlTransaction tran)
{
    var props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(type)
                    .Cast<PropertyDescriptor>()
                    .ToArray();
}
```

Called like this (assuming that you have a list of elements of the same type, ignoring the type of the list by purpose):

```
if (childList.Count > 0)
{
  BulkInsert(childList[0].GetType(), "Images",  conn, tran);
}
```

Or **if** your `T` argument actually *is* useful:

```
  BulkInsert(typeof(T), "Images",  conn, tran);
```

Everything else, Linq stuff and other reflection stuff may raise some questions as well, but I try to keep it short here and focus on your first problem. You should try to not put too many things into a single question.

Comment: passing the .GetType() did the trick, I cant believe i overlooked that ;), appreciate your time